# Internet Retailer Sharing Customer Information on Review Site

Tags: internet, privacy, terms-of-service, defamation

Recently, I had a poor experience with an online retailer. After the retailed failed to resolve the issue, I filed a BBB complaint.

The retailer then notified me that they had posted my "customer information" e.g. name, full address, email address on a website which enables retailers to "rate" customers.

The retailers [terms of service](http://www.madisonseating.com/terms-of-use.html) and [privacy policy](http://www.madisonseating.com/security-and-privacy.html)

My question is, based on those terms and the privacy policy, do they have the right to share my information in that manner?

Comment: What jurisdiction?

Comment: Seriously? There's a site to rate *customers*? What has the world become...

Answer (score 1):

**No**

They explicitly say:

> Please provide us with your name and phone number. We will be sure your name is removed from the list we share with other organizations

They have not done this. Add this fact to your BBB complaint and write them a C&D letter.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. The fact that they have shared your personal information online to another site violates their Privacy Policy.

> Please provide us with your name and phone number. We will be sure your name is removed from the list we share with other organizations

With respect to your email address, they did explicitly state that they can share it:

> From time to time, we make the e-mail addresses of those who access our site available to other reputable organizations whose products or services we think you might find interesting. If you do not want us to share your e-mail address with other companies or organizations, please let us know by calling us at the number provided above.
>
> From time to time, we make our customer e-mail list available to other reputable organizations whose products or services we think you might find interesting. If you do not want us to share your e-mail address with other companies or organizations, please let us know by calling us at the number provided above.

Honestly, the company sounds like a horrible place. I wouldn't shop with them again. You should add it to your BBB complaint, linking to the relevant sections of the Privacy Policy as well.